# Module Not Found when using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a virtualenv that uses Python 3 and am currently using pytest for testing. I've packaged a program called "process_expiring_passwords" and import this package from my general script file called "pep.py". I've also used pip in my virtualenv to install my process_expiring_passwords package.

When I go to run my tests, however, I get the following error:

> ImportError while importing test module
>   '/home/username/projects/process-expiring-passwords/tests/test_process_expiring_passwords.py'.
>
> Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
>
> Traceback: tests/test_process_expiring_passwords.py:3: in 
>       from process_expiring_passwords import ProcessExpiringPasswords process_expiring_passwords/process_expiring_passwords.py:16: in
>   
>       from process_expiring_passwords.models.ProcessExpiringPasswordsLog
>
> \ E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'process_expiring_passwords.models'; 'process_expiring_passwords' is
>   not a package

Is there a particular reason why I can use my package from my pep.py general script file while pytest is unable to find said package?

The essential parts of the code related to this issue are as follows:

pep.py:

```
from process_expiring_passwords.process_expiring_passwords \
    import ProcessExpiringPasswords

pep = ProcessExpiringPasswords()
pep.process()
```

process_expiring_passwords/process_expiring_passwords.py:

```
from process_expiring_passwords.models.ProcessExpiringPasswordsLog \
    import ProcessExpiringPasswordsLog

class ProcessExpiringPasswords:
    def __init__(self):
        self.example = 0
    def process():
        pepl = ProcessExpiringPasswordsLog()
```

process_expiring_passwords/models/ProcessExpiringPasswordsLog.py:

```
class ProcessExpiringPasswordsLog():
    def __init__(self):
        self.example = 0
```

process_expiring_passwords/setup.py:

```
# ref: https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py
# ref: http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='process_expiring_passwords',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    description='Process expiring passwords',
    license='MIT',
    install_requires=[
        'apiclient',
        'google-api-python-client',
        'httplib2',
        'mysqlclient',
        'oauth2client',
        'requests',
        'SQLAlchemy',
    ],
)
```

tests/test_process_expiring_passwords.py:

```
from process_expiring_passwords import ProcessExpiringPasswords

def test_pep():
    pep = ProcessExpiringPasswords()
    assert pep is not None
```

Project structure:

```
process_expiring_passwords
    pep.py
    process_expiring_passwords
        __init__.py
        models
            __init__.py
            ProcessExpiringPasswordsLog.py
        process_expiring_passwords.py
        setup.py
    tests
        test_process_expiring_passwords.py
```

Notes:

- Updated code example and setup.py based on feedback from Matt
  Messersmith.

Comment: The only reason that pytest doesn' t find your module ist that it's not in your PATH. As you said you installed it (I suppose with `pip -e .` the only reason I can think of is that `pytest` is not installed in your virtualenv and thus you run the "main python" variant which can not find your module in the PATH. Install pytest in your virtualenv and it should work.

Comment: @MrLeeh Thank you for the comment/suggestion! I've double-checked, and the pytest that I'm currently using already appears to be in my virtualenv.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks for the suggestions! I've tried the conftest.py approach just now but I get the same results that I received when I tried the last two of your suggestions previously. I still end up getting a similar (but shortened) error: Traceback: tests/test_process_expiring_passwords.py:3: in <module>
    from process_expiring_passwords import ProcessExpiringPasswords
E   ImportError: cannot import name 'ProcessExpiringPasswords'

Comment: disregard my previous comment, I now see what the issue is. You have the package having the same name as the module, so when you do `import process_expiring_passwords` inside `process_expiring_passwords/process_expiring_passwords.py`, you don't import the parent package. Add lines `import process_expiring_passwords; print(process_expiring_passwords.__file__)` to `process_expiring_passwords.py` and verify that you import the module instead.

Comment: switching to a relative import inside `process_expiring_passwords.py` should fix the issue: `from .models.UserAccountStatus import UserAccountStatus`, but I can't test it out myself right now.

Comment: @hoefling When I try the relative import approach I get this error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Overall, the package structure looks a bit messy to me, can you enhance the code in question to a [mcve]? Your setup script resides in the package `process_expiring_passwords` which it presumably should collect and install, how do you pass the package to `packages` list? Do you use `setuptools.find_packages` for that? The same naming of the package and module may be only a complication that distracts from the actual error.

Comment: @hoefling I've added more detail to this question.

Comment: @hoefling Here is the output I get from your comment about `print(process_expiring_passwords.__file__)`: `/home/username/projects/process-expiring-passwords/process_expiring_passwords/process_expiring_passwords.py` . Should this be pointing elsewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182609/discussion-between-hoefling-and-summea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [an extended conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182609/discussion-between-hoefling-and-summea) about this issue, here are the following steps that especially helped based on comments from @hoefling and after adding `packages=find_packages(),` to `setup.py` based on answer from @Matt Messersmith:

1. moved `setup.py` to root project directory
2. deleted `__pycache__` files
3. made imports relative in main module file

   process_expiring_passwords/process_expiring_passwords.py:

   `from .models.ProcessExpiringPasswordsLog \
       import ProcessExpiringPasswordsLog`
4. ran `python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib;
   print(get_python_lib())"`
5. removed old package line from `easy-install.pth` *(which should be found using the resulting path from the previous step)*
6. ran `pip install -e .`
7. added `process_expiring_passwords` to test file's import section:

   `from process_expiring_passwords.process_expiring_passwords \
       import ProcessExpiringPasswords`

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't quite work as posted, I modified it to have the `self` keyword in your constructors and member functions. After that, I could get pep.py to run.

> Is there a particular reason why I can use my package from my pep.py
>   general script file while pytest is unable to find said package?

Yes, when you are in your top level `process_expiring_passwords` directory, you can run `pep.py`, because you'll be getting a "local" import of the package.

The fact that the test doens't run has little to do with `pytest`, and more to do with what your import statement looks like and the fact that you're not building a package:

```
from process_expiring_passwords import ProcessExpiringPasswords
```

You haven't created a package called `process_expiring_passwords`. You can verify this by doing `python setup.py bdist_wheel` (or just do `sdist` and unzip the tarball), unzipping the wheel, and noting that there are no packages present.

Typically, you need to install the packages `python setup.py install` (this plops the distributable in your site-packages), and you also have to name the packages in setup.py (`find_packages()` is your friend), and then your test should work (more or less) as expected.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still have a lot to learn, but I've added `packages=find_packages(),` to my setup.py file and have tried installing the package. It seems to install successfully, but I still cannot use this import statement: `from process_expiring_passwords import ProcessExpiringPasswords` without getting this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'ProcessExpiringPasswords'`. Could there be any other steps that I've missed when following your example of using `python setup.py install`?

Comment: @summea Usually `setup.py` is at the highest level: no `__init__.py` in the same dir as `setup.py` (and that's the setup i'm most familiar with). You might be able to get it to work how you have it with a different import statement, or changing your call to `setup`, but TBH I just don't know all the ins and outs of setup.py (it's somewhat intricate). Try creating a new directory (package), maybe call it `my_package` (you can rename it later). Move the `__init__.py` and `process_ex_pass.py` into it, and then try `from my_package.process_expiring_passwords import ProcessExpiringPasswords`. HTH.