# Python pytest - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompts'

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Running `pytest` in the terminal results in the below error. The application runs fine with `python3 main.py` from the `src/` directory, however pytest throws this error.

```
____________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_with_pytest.py ____________________________________________________________________________________
    ImportError while importing test module '/Users/Lucas/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/tests/test_with_pytest.py'.
    Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
    Traceback:
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    tests/test_with_pytest.py:1: in <module>
        from src import csv_methods
    src/csv_methods.py:2: in <module>
        from prompts import *
    E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompts'
```

I am using pipenv for the virtual env.

Project structure:

```
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── __pycache__
│   └── ...
├── requirements.txt
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── app_objects.md
│   ├── asset.py
│   ├── command_line.py
│   ├── csv_data
│   │   └── assets.csv
│   ├── csv_methods.py
│   ├── input.py
│   ├── log.log
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── menu.py
│   └── prompts.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_with_pytest.py
```

I have tried the popular answers and common results such as adding `__init__.py` files within the test, src folder and the route directory. Note the **init**.py files are blank, I have tried the recommendations from the following posts such as adding in  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748464/pytest-cannot-import-module-while-python-can?noredirect=1&lq=1) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54895002/modulenotfounderror-with-pytest) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011469/module-not-found-when-using-pytest?rq=3)

I saw the solution about adding `PYTHONPATH=. pytest` to the project but its unclear in which file etc to add this.

Also tried running with `python3 -m pytest` but no luck.

`python3 -m site`

```
sys.path = [
    '/Users/Lucas/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
    '/Users/Lucas/.local/share/virtualenvs/asset_management_system-GiLvwx5p/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/Users/Lucas/Library/Python/3.11' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/Users/Lucas/Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

**css_methods.py**

```
#  Functions to perform read, write to csv data stores
from prompts import *
import csv
import os
from tabulate import tabulate
import logging

---snip---
```

**test_with_pytest.py**

```
from src import csv_methods
from src import prompts

def test_always_passes():
    assert True
```

**Pipfile.lock**

```
"_meta": {
        "hash": {
            "sha256": "d2f84cfd3b709ff81d112ff5862ef667b82358c63d00cdf29b529b0535b4c08a"
        },
        "pipfile-spec": 6,
        "requires": {
            "python_version": "3.11"
        },
        "sources": [
            {
                "name": "pypi",
                "url": "https://pypi.org/simple",
                "verify_ssl": true
            }
        ]
```

`python --version Python 3.11.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decided whether `src` is a single package or if it's just a collection of individual modules.

In `test_with_pytest`, you are using `from src import ...`, meaning you are treating `src` as a package. For this you need an `__init__.py` file.

When running `python main.py`, and when doing imports like `import prompts`, you are treating it as if it's just a collection of single-file modules.

You probably should treated it as a single package (and rename the folder something more descriptive/unique than `src`). Then you would always, in all files, use `from src import ...` or `from src.prompts import ...`, and would run it with `python -m src.main`.

Comment: This was really help I used `from src.prompts import` and created a pyproject.toml file with `[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [
  ".", "src",
]`